# jQuery auto scroll a div Up & down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autoscroll

I have written a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7e3d440/8/) that scrolls a div up and down automatically which is working fine. But there is an issue when it scrolls down, it doesn't show the last row ("String4" in this case). can anybody help me to sort this out please.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <p>string1</p>
    <p>string</p>
    <p>string</p>
    <p>string</p>
    <p>string</p>
    <p>string</p>
    <p>string0</p>
    <p>string1</p>
    <p>string2</p>
    <p>string3</p>
    <p>string4</p>
     <p> </p>
</div>
```

and js stuff:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.content').height() > $('.container').height()) {
        setInterval(function () {

            start();
       }, 3000); 

    }
});

function animateContent(direction) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.container').height() - $('.content').height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }

    console.log("animationOffset:"+animationOffset);
    $('.content').animate({ "marginTop": (animationOffset)+ "px" }, 5000);
}

function up(){
    animateContent("up")
}
function down(){
    animateContent("down")
}

function start(){
 setTimeout(function () {
    down();
}, 2000);
 setTimeout(function () {
    up();
}, 2000);
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("wait...");
}, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is good solution

check here only

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.content').height() > $('.container').height()) {
        setInterval(function () {

            start();
       }, 3000); 
   
    }
});

function animateContent(direction) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.container').height() - $('.content').height()-30;
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }

    console.log("animationOffset:"+animationOffset);
    $('.content').animate({ "marginTop": (animationOffset)+ "px" }, 5000);
}

function up(){
    animateContent("up")
}
function down(){
    animateContent("down")
}

function start(){
 setTimeout(function () {
    down();
}, 2000);
 setTimeout(function () {
    up();
}, 2000);
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("wait...");
}, 5000);
}
```

```css
.container { height:250px; background:red; padding:0 10px; overflow:hidden; }
.content { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>string1</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string0</p>
        <p>string1</p>
        <p>string2</p>
        <p>string3</p>
        <p>string4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

make

```
var animationOffset = $('.container').height() - $('.content').height()-30;
```

as may be padding interrupts your height.

I have removed your empty p tag.

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/f7e3d440/11/)

Comment: no, it works only if you have the <br> appended as the accepted answer. remove the <br> from fiddle and try with your code, it doen't work. Thanks for the try nirmal.

Comment: still the same machan

Comment: you can check code right here. while the answer you marked as correct. you can not see your border bottom. Which I don't think so is good thing. Else selecting to go with which is your choice.

Comment: That is now working like a charm! and a great clean solution. Thanks Nirmal.

Answer (score 2):

Try This: Might be stupid but does the work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>string1</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string</p>
        <p>string0</p>
        <p>string1</p>
        <p>string2</p>
        <p>string3</p>
        <p>string4</p>
         <p><br> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7e3d440/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following code:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('content');
myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
```

[Div Overflow Scroll-to-bottom: Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606560/div-overflow-scroll-to-bottom-is-it-possible)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/632251/How-to-make-div-scroll-to-bottom-on-load

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle works great for dynamically generated content. https://jsfiddle.net/bsxcL71L/2/

```
function down() {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: hg}, 20000);
up();
};
function up() {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#start').offset().top }, 20000);
down();
};
$(document).ready(function () {
hg = $('#content').height() - 420;
down();
});
```